# InvalidCastException: Unable cast generic List to object

Tags: c#, casting, generic-list

Could someone please explain to me why the following cast does not work and the solution to the problem.

I have a `GroupedResult`:

```
public class GroupedResult<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> source;

    public GroupedResult(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.Key = key;
    }
}

public class Bacon 
{
}
```

I would like to cast the `List<string, Bacon>` to `List<string, object>`. I have tried the following and other ways.

```
var list = new List<GroupedResult<string, Bacon>>
    {
        new GroupedResult<string, Bacon>("1", new List<Bacon>()),
        new GroupedResult<string, Bacon>("2", new List<Bacon>())
    };

var result = list.Cast<GroupedResult<string, object>>().ToList();
```

But I always get the following error:

> InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'GroupedResult`2[System.String,UserQuery+Bacon]' to type 'GroupedResult`2[System.String,System.Object]'.

Comment: Classes are invariant so a `GropuedResult<string, Bacon>` is not a `GroupedResult<string, object>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that to work you'd have to use an interface instead of class type.

```
public interface IGroupResult<TKey, out TElement>
{
    TKey Key { get; set; }
}

public class GroupedResult<TKey, TElement> : IGroupResult<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> source;

    public GroupedResult(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.Key = key;
    }
}

public class Bacon
{

}
```

Then you could do something like

```
IGroupResult<string, Bacon> g = new GroupedResult<string, Bacon>("1", new List<Bacon>());

var result = (IGroupResult<string, object>)g;
```

That's because co-variance is only allowed on interfaces and delegates, but not classes.  Note that you should only mark a type as co-variant if it only comes out of the interface (method return type and read only properties).

Though you should ask yourself why you want to cast something to `object` when you're working with generics.  The main point of generics is to avoid having to use the `object` type as a catch all and this could indicate a flaw in your design that you might want to rethink.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to start with a GroupedResult < string, object> then you COULD do this

```
new GroupedResult<string, object>("2", new List<Bacon>())
```

Answer (score 0):

why aren'y you using `GroupedResult<string, object>` instead of `GroupedResult<string, Bacon>`? like this:

```
var list = new List<GroupedResult<string, object>>
    {
        new GroupedResult<string, object>("1", new List<Bacon>()),
        new GroupedResult<string, object>("2", new List<Bacon>())
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `Cast` method in your `GroupedResult` class and use it to do the casting!

```
public class GroupedResult<TKey, TElement>
{
    public TKey Key { get; set; }

    private readonly IEnumerable<TElement> source;

    public GroupedResult(TKey key, IEnumerable<TElement> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
        this.Key = key;
    }

    public GroupedResult<TKey, object> Cast()
    {
        return new GroupedResult<TKey, object>(Key, source.Cast<object>());
    }
}

public class Bacon
{ 
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

   var list = new List<GroupedResult<string, Bacon>>
   {
        new GroupedResult<string, Bacon>("1", new List<Bacon>()),
        new GroupedResult<string, Bacon>("2", new List<Bacon>())
    };

    // var result = list.Cast<GroupedResult<string, object>>().ToList();
    List<GroupedResult<string,object>> result = list.Select(B => B.Cast()).ToList();
}
```